# Including one GWT module in another

Tags: gwt

For a couple of years we been having three GWT modules:

Module1 (has entry point)
Module2 (has entry point)
Common (has NO entry point)

Module1 and Module2 have been living deprecate lives and the only shared code between them have been put in common.

Now, we want to have functionality from Module2 in Module1, but not the other way around.

What are my options and what's recommended?

Let Module1 inherit Module2? Will Module1 then get Common both by itself and from Module?

Move Module2 into Module1 and create one monolith?

Answer (score 1):

try to move functionality needed for both Modules into the Common module.
And inherit Common module in Module 1 and 2.